# Delete documents using their _ids as a comparison

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, increment, delete-file

So, straight to the problem. We have many clients that have their local MongoDB, everyday new data are generated and stored in .TSV files, these files are uploaded to their database using mongoimport (insert, update and merge) to achieve a, lets say, incremental load.

We already have a _id field that works as Key for mongo, so this way mongo automatically can detect if a document already exists or not, if not he will import that document, it is kinda a incremental load (again, mongoimport mentioned above).

Since we already have the insert and update working correctly, what we are trying to do right now is the following:

1. How to automatically delete the documents that are in the local mongo and are not in the .TSV files?

Remembering that we already have the _id created and maybe we can use it as a comparison key.

Basically what we want to achieve is that the data stored in the client's local mongo be the same as the data store in the .TSV files that we import, so the mongo will be a "mirror" of the client's data. All that without deleting and uploading everything everyday.

I hope it was clear enough to understand what we want to do.

Thanks!

Comment: How many documents are we talking about?

Comment: A lot of documents, the number will vary for each clients, but we can say that everyday we might need to delete a few dozens to even thousands, but I think in the vast majority it will in the hundreds

Answer (score 0):

What I'd be inclined to do is replace the mongoimport with an equivalent pymongo load routine (that will have to be developed) that loads the data and adds a "LastUpdated" field with the current date/time added.

Once completed, delete any documents that have not been updated since the start of the load.

Good luck!

Comment: We could add the LastUpdate field in our .TSV files since we have fully control over them. Do you have any idea or tips on how to implement the part that deles the documents that have not been updated? I don't know if we should do that in python (if possible) or create a query/routine inside mongo.